# How to stop Oracle dbms_job

Tags: database, oracle, dbms-job

My dbms_job has been running for nearly thirty days.

The number of total time keeps rising, but I can't find any info of the running job.

When I execute sql that is "select * from dba_jobs;", the result shows no job is running.

I set it to broken, but it doesn't work.

How can I stop this dbms_job safely?

[image: the job's information]

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you're using the ancient dbms_job instead of dbms_scheduler? dbms_scheduler is more maintainable, easier to use and overall much superior IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

`DBA_JOBS` lists all the jobs created in the database. You could use `DBA_JOBS_RUNNING` view to list all jobs that are currently running in the instance.

> When I execute sql that is "select * from dba_jobs;", the result shows no job is running.

This shows all the jobs created using `DBMS_JOBS` package. The job might have created using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package.

```
SQL> select job from user_jobs;

       JOB
----------
        99
```

I have created only one job using `DBMS_JOB`package which is called `99`.
Others are created using `DBMS_SCHEDULER`package which can be seen using:

```
SQL> select job_name from user_scheduler_jobs;
```

As per the documentation-

> #### Stopping a Job
>
> Note that, once a job is started and running, there is no easy way to stop the job.

Its not easy to stop the job.

Don't know which version of Oracle database are you using. But starting with Oracle 10g You use the following query to list the scheduled jobs.

```
SQL>select * from all_scheduler_jobs;
```

> #### ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS
>
> ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS displays information about the Scheduler jobs accessible to the current user.[More...](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2049.htm#REFRN20348)

Use the following query to find the currently running job.

```
SQL>select job_name, session_id, running_instance, elapsed_time, cpu_used
from user_scheduler_running_jobs;
```

And to stop-

```
SQL>EXEC DBMS_SCHEDULER.STOP_JOB (job_name => 'JOB_NAME');
```

Comment: `xxx_JOBS` and `xxx_SCHEDULER_JOBS` are two completely different beasts. The former has been around for ages and is outdated, the latter is the successor.

Comment: If the graceful stop doesn't work, you may also try to stop it immediately using the force parameter: `EXEC DBMS_SCHEDULER.STOP_JOB (job_name => 'JOBNAME', force => TRUE);`.

Answer (score 2):

Short of killing the session, you're out of luck.

From the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm#BABHCBFD):

> Note that, once a job is started and running, there is no easy way to stop the job.

That's one of the many reasons why you shouldn't use `dbms_job` anymore. Use `dbms_scheduler` instead.

Comment: Actually I don't know why use dbms_job,it exist before.
I want to know why I get no rsult when I excute "select * from dba_jobs;".
How do I get the sesion and kill it?

Comment: Is the job present in DBA_JOBS_RUNNING ? If yes, you can obtain the SID from there.

Comment: No, the job is not present in DBA_JOBS_RUNNING.

Answer (score 0):

checkout SID in "select * from DBA_JOBS_RUNNNG"
thats session ID 
kill that session and thats it changes will be rolled back, so it can take "more" time to abort than letting it finish if that bulk update was 90% complete....